# Macro that adds new row based of calculated data based on sheet 1 input

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I ran into a problem I couldn't fix using formulas. I have two Excel sheets, representing a horse race with point system situation.

Sheet 1 shows manual data. It includes: names, ID of the person, their horse name, date they raced and points they received for that race.
Sheet 2 will need to automatically generate a new row of a person that participated as well as points they received that date and the total points and number of attendances (but only if they participated or else the row should not be generated at all).
Sheet 2 should display all the racers and their attended dates they raced that continue to populate if they race and points received those race days. These should be stacked on top of each other, racer after racer displaying. This is what I've tried so far.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Sheets("Output").Select
Selectio**n.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

Manual Excel data here (shows both sheets without formulas. This is how it 'should' look https://app.box.com/s/50irov2cwfab6tftoen2

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with the existing code?

Comment: That link is dead for me, though I am behind a firewall.  It sounds like you are going to have a lot of individual rows per person - raw data - on the first sheet, and you want the second sheet to just summarize all of the raw data.  This is something that MS Access would be extremely good at, if you'd consider it.  If not, I think your best bet is a Pivot-Table.

Comment: @DavidZemens No problems with that small snippet but i was trying to see if it was possible to create an macro that did what I needed it to do. **1** Punch in manual information for person 1, **2** Auto generate new row in second sheet w/ new updated information for the rider. **3** give a summary on sheet 2 that states all the riders data as a whole.

Comment: @Blackhawk yes you're correct. I do want the second sheet to summarize all the data. A nice direction towards Pivot-Table in doing this would be great. I have Office Mac 2011 which doesn't include Access. Would love to get this to function on excel. Thank you Blackhawk for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

To create a summary with a Pivot Table, take a look at [this tutorial](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-create-pivot-table-excel).  After you have your Pivot Table created, for your specific problem you would want to add `name`, `ID of the person`, and `horse name` in the Row Labels box; add a Count of `race date` and the Sum of `points recieved` into the Values box.  The table will list the aggregate stats for each person with subtotals for each additional Row Label, which you can turn off by if you don't need.

Comment: I have managed to create the Pivot Table and set an aggregation for for points received and race dates but I actually wanted to show the races they received points in underneath the race they **attended**. I keep getting a **(blank)** statement description underneath the _Row Labels_ when I do add this. It would be nice to set a rule so if they didn't attend, eliminate that race date altogether for that rider which is my goal. Thanx @Blackhawk

Comment: I wish you can somehow see that link above to see what I mean. @Blackhawk

Comment: @Artist701, I was able to look at your data over the weekend.  The issue here is that for the Pivot Table (or an Access database solution, which would suit your data and output goals much better), all of the data needs to be in columns (fields in Access database parlance).  The second half of your data is a set of headers, one for each race and date.  You need to replace that with three columns: `Date`, `Race`, `Points`.  This will mean multiple row entries for riders with multiple race scores.  Making this change enables the use of a Pivot Table.